# OutWatch: enforce changes on Elements to be shown immediately

Tags: scala.js, outwatch

I want to have a loading spinner that can be used from everywhere. So I created a BoolHandler:

```
val loadingSpinnerEvents = createBoolHandler()
```

Which is bound to the loading spinner div:

```
val loadingSpinner = div(
  hidden <-- loadingSpinnerEvents
  , Icon.loadingIcon
)
```

So I do the following:

```
def reducer(previousState: State, action: Action): State = {
  var st = previousState
  loadingSpinnerEvents <-- Observable.create { obs =>
    obs.next(false)
    st = newState(previousState, action)
    Future {
    // do the long running work

    }.onComplete { _ =>
      obs.next(true)
      obs.complete()
    }
  }
  st
}
```

According to println output, the boolean values are handled correctly and immediately.

The problem is that element changes are shown only after the whole work is done.

Is there a way to enforce that or do I miss something.

Comment: What kind of work are you doing between the two bindings? Note that this is not exactly the "OutWatch" way of doing things. You're creating two bindings to the same events, which might be a misconception. The `<--` operator does not send a single event, but creates a subscription for an observable. If you're just sending a single value, it does not really make sense.

Comment: You are right. But how would you show the user that there is work in progress. So show the loading spinner when starting the calculation - and hiding it when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Have you tried using my solution below? :)

Comment: yes, but as you mentioned this works only if the code is synchronous. The work between is manipulating the store. The reaction to that is asynchronous.

Comment: I also added now synchronous work - now the log looks good, but the div is not shown. This is maybe because it is called within the reducer method of the store.

Comment: You can't have `var`s in your Store, I suggest doing this without a Store, or build an asynchronous Store :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an Observable that starts with false, and then does some of the work and turns to true. I.e.

```
val loadingSpinnerEvents = Observable.create{ obs =>
  obs.next(false)
  //do some work here
  obs.next(true)
}
```

However this depends on the work being done. If it's synchronous, this approach should work fairly well.

If your work is asynchronous and takes a callback, you can also wrap it in an Observable:

```
val loadingSpinnerEvents = Observable.create{ obs => 
  obs.next(false)
  // do work with callback
  doWork {
    obs.next(true)
    obs.complete()
  }
}
```

Comment: Both solution do not work for me. I think the problem might be that I call that in the reducer method of the store, which is also an Observable.

Comment: I adjusted my question